# "Vieler im Einzelnen" und "mituntergelaufen"?

Tags: meaning-in-context

I have two questions regarding the sentence

> Dass bei dieser ungeheuren Arbeit **Vieler im Einzelnen** auch mancherlei Irrtümer **mituntergelaufen** sind, das ist natürlich und zuletzt für das Gesammtergebnis gar nicht so schlimm.

1. Does "***Vieler im Einzelnen** auch mancherlei Irrtümer*" refer to "***many** various mistakes **in** relation to **the details***"?
2. Am I correctly interpreting "*Irrtümer **mituntergelaufen***" as something like "*mistakes has **sneaked in***"?

Comment: You should really cite your sources.

Comment: Another option is that a space is missing between *mit* and *untergelaufen*

Answer (score 6):

You have to split the sentence differently:

> Dass bei dieser ungeheuren Arbeit Vieler …

It's the **work of many**.

There's no verb *mitunterlaufen*. It's in the same league as *to misunderestimate*. In addition the *Partizip II* of inseparable prefixed verbs as *unterlaufen* retains the prefix and skips the *-ge-*, so it must be *unterlaufen*, not *untergelaufen*.

What was probably meant was

> … im Einzelnen auch mancherlei Irrtümer unterlaufen sind …

Comment: *mit-* is a semi-productive prefix that can be added to more or less any verb, indicating that another process occurred in addition to the explicitly described process: *mitfliegen* = You're flying somewhere and I'm coming, too; *miterledigen* = We're dealing with this in combination with that other thing that we're already doing, etc. So there doesn't need to be an actual verb *mitunterlaufen*.

Comment: @KilianFoth Es geht im das _**ge-**_ in _mitunter**ge**laufen_.

Comment: I have still no idea what *mitunterlaufen* should mean. *Unterlaufen* with its two variants is complicated enough.

Comment: @Janka: I read it as two words, "mit untergelaufen", where "mit" is used in the same way as extending "das ist dabei" to "das ist mit dabei". But I have to admit I never thought about the grammar of this usage of "mit", and I'd suppose it's mostly colloquial.

Answer (score 2):

First, let us correct the orthographic errors and stylistic flaws of the sentence:

> Dass bei dieser ungeheuren Arbeit **Vieler** **im Einzelnen** auch mancherlei Irrtümer **<s>mit</s>unter<s>ge</s>laufen** sind, <s>das</s> ist <s>natürlich und zuletzt</s> für das Gesam<s>m</s>tergebnis gar nicht so schlimm.

Now, let us turn to your questions.

> regarding 1.
>
> - die Arbeit **Vieler** ⇆ the works **of many**
> - **im Einzelnen** ⇆ **in detail**
>
> regarding 2.
>
> - Irrtümer sind [**unterlaufen**](https://www.dwds.de/wb/unterlaufen#1) ⇆ mistakes **occurred** / **sneaked in**

Thus, the relative clause can be interpreted as follows:

> ... that, during the tremendous works **of many**, **in detail** also several mistakes **sneaked in** ...

Comment: while I agree to cut the 2nd m, I disagree to say that "das ist natürlich und zuletzt" is a stylistic flaw. Consequently this would eliminate "ungeheuren" and "mancherlei", even "gar nicht so schlimm" would turn out "okay". I see it just as characteristics without any error. The core aspect of the answer: I agree.

Comment: Wer häufig längere Texte schreibt oder redigiert wird aus stilistischen Gründen sehr wohl solche Füllwörter streichen, sofern mit ihnen nicht bestimmte Effekte erzeugt werden sollen.